# iOS SDK retine images vs using bigger images for smaller placeholders

Tags: ios, ios5, retina-display

Is it the same if I use a big image i.e. a 40x40 image in a 20x20 place holder or a @2x image for retina?

I mean, I have two alternatives:
 - use a 20x20 image.png and 40x40 image@2x.png
 - use a 40x40 image.png

Is it the same?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious too. I actually would assume that it wouldn't really make a difference, just a smaller submission to Apple in the end. Of course if you have very detailed graphics for the retina these will look awful on the non-retina phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only retina images and leaving the down-scaling on non-retina devices up to the system is possible but not recommendable in all cases.

It really depends on the contents of your graphics. If, for example you are using vector based graphics as your source (sharp lines etc.), then offering only the retina images will result into washed, blurry images on non-retina displays.

Again, it is possible and entirely fine if your content still looks good enough.